# Parameter substitution in JDBCTemplate::execute

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

While browsing the JDBCTemplate API I couldn't find a version of the JDBCTemplate::execute method which supports parameter substitution, i.e. something like the usual

```
template.execute("some sql statement with parameter ?", "the parameter")
```

which is available for most of the `query`, `update` etc. methods in JDBCTemplate.

I was wondering whether this is just me not being able to find it or whether it is really missing and if so, why?

Comment: and why would the `execute` be different then `update`? Update internally uses the `execute` method and can take whatever sql statement you like.

Comment: not sure whether execute uses update internally, at least execute(final String sql) doesn't afaik, maybe the other methods do. I am not saying that on cannot use update to achieve the same thing but my guess is they provided the execute method for some (maybe only semantic) reason and I was only wondering if there is a particular reason for not providing the parameter substitution in this case.

Comment: As stated `update` uses `execute`, all methods that execute a query end up using one of the `execute` methods. The `execute` methods are the core of the functionality of the `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: ok, got it. thx for the comments.